# Open Hyperlink(URL) on browser directory in KML

Tags: hyperlink, kml, google-earth

I write down Hyperlink in balloon in KML.
When I clicked it, URL is opened on Google earth. But I want to open it on browser like chrome.
I know we have that button to open it on browser but I would like to know if there is anyway to open it on browser without clicking that button.

I have no idea what I can do for this...

I'm expecting when I clicked hyperlink in balloon in KML, webpage opened on browser not on Google earth.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you click a URL link in popup balloon in Google Earth Pro, the contents by default will be displayed within a web-browser like frame inside Google Earth Pro.

There should be a link above the browser frame called "Open In Google Chrome" or whatever the default web browser is.

You can change the default behavior when clicking on a link.

Tool > Options > General > Display

Check "*Show web browser results in external browser*" option to always show web content in the default web browser.